# select distinct articles in views not working

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to remove the duplicate selected article.
Even though my filters are simple and direct I am still getting duplicate articles
Here's screenshot of my view
[image]

Attempts I used:
 1. I have applied Query Settings Distinct.
 2. I tried to use aggregation but I got sql error.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache, and/or disabled view's caching? Have you looked at the sql query? See [Configure Views for debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/configure-views-for-debugging)

Comment: Yes I have cleared cache but still duplicate

Comment: Yes there is distinct in the query. however the result are duplicate

Comment: How to execute the query in mysql. the bracelet fields should be replaced ?

Comment: The bracelets are there to add the table prefix - if any. If you're not using a table prefix you can replace them by an empty string.

Comment: When I have a problem with views that I can't figure out, I rebuild the view and look at the preview at each step, until the problem appears. When duplicate rows appear, compare the SQL of the step with the duplicate rows to the one before. Also at this point you can see if distinct and/or aggregate work. If one does, continue building it until distinct doesn't work, or aggregate causes that error. Instead of rebuilding your view, you can do the reverse, and remove one setting at a time, until the duplicate rows go away. I would start with removing the relationship to Paragraph.

Comment: @runswithscissors great advice. I found that the relationship causing the duplicate.

Comment: Good to hear. Hopefully you don't need the relationship to do what you want. If you do, then you need to figure out why that relationship causes the duplicates, like if there are multiple paragraphs for each article (should there be?). See if you can alter the SQL for the query to get the duplicates to go away, and then search for an answer on how to do it in views. For example, if changing a `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` (or versa-visa) works, then search for _views change left join to inner_. I'd also search the SQL error you get when aggregation is on, and try to fix the query.

Comment: @runswithscissors now it returns no duplicate. I just rebuild the view and it returns no duplicate even though similar query

Comment: Great! You should [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You will be able to mark it as the correct answer after 48 hours.